# React does not respect the settimeout

Tags: reactjs, react-native, settimeout

I'm trying to process a large number of lines and i need them to be done in a block of 150, but react doesn't respect them and does them all at the same time. Here is my code, I removed what would not change the result.

```
        const sleep = (ms) =>
            new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    callback()
                    resolve()
                }, ms)
            })
        const isNumberMultipleOf150 = number => {
            const result = number / 150
            return result % 150 === 0
        }
    
    importLines.forEach(async (line, index) => {
        line = line.split('#')[0];
        var pid = line.trim();
        if (isNumberMultipleOf150(currentLines)) {
            await sleep(10000)
            return
        }
        if (pid) {
            allPromise.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const iline = currentLines;
                this.getProductData(pid, function (prod) {
                    currentLines = currentLines + 1;
                    if (prod.id) {
                        //do
                    } 
                    resolve();
                });
            }));
        } 
    })

    Promise.all(allPromise).then(function () {
        callback(errors, responseArray, responsePids);
    });
```

Comment: you call `sleep(10000)` but the function takes a `callback` before the `ms` delay.

Comment: @EmileBergeron sorry but i don't understand what to do to fix my problem

Comment: Your sleep function takes 2 arguments, you're passing only one.

Comment: @EmileBergeron 
even removing the error still

Comment: Agreed with @EmileBergeron callback is missing and also other stuff :importLines, currentLines, allPromises, getProductData. Furthermore, there is nothing inside this function that is relevant to react to influence its behavior.

Comment: @SimonDX I didn't understand what you meant, I removed part of the code to not pollute, can you post what should I do for my code respected the settimeout?

Comment: Use a for loop instead of forEach, that should do what you want.